# Alignment of a 3rd column when container-fluid is used

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to edit a page containing 3 columns. I'm trying to find a way such that the third column should be immediately below the first.

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://max[enter image description here][1]cdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>Resize this page to see the responsive effect!</p> 
    </div>
      
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h2>London</h2>
          <p>London is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
          with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h2>Paris</h2>
          <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
          <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
          <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
       <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
       <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
       <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
       <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
       <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
          it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2>Tokyo</h2>
          <p>Tokyo is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,
          and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here, I expect the data corresponding to Tokyo to be immediately below London's data. (However, it is taking it to below the maximum of London and Paris .)

Answer (score 0):

OP wants no `.row` padding, so he can do this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">London content</div>
    <div class="col">Paris content</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6">Tokyo content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-fast-cutuk?fontsize=14). [Docs on this here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#equal-width) (scroll to 2nd example).

Looks like this:
[image: code above looks like this]

**Original answer:**

As per bootstrap's documentation, simply put your Tokyo column in a new `row` below your first `row` containing London & Paris.

Also, if you're going to define col-width, the max is 12.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
      with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tokyo</h2>
      <p>Tokyo is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,
      and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap layout docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/). Since you're new: if this solves your issue, tick this answer :) (and a vote if you want)

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't solve the problem. There is still a lot of gap between London and Tokyo. What is needed is column-wise alignment and not row-wise.

Comment: Updated answer to remove row. @GauravDVerma

Comment: There is a row still....What is needed is 2 independent columns with many elements. There should not be any row in the display...

Comment: I guess you didn't take the time to understand bootstrap's layout system then. It needs a `container`, `row`, then `col` in that order. If you just have a `col` in `container`, it may work, but certainly not as intended. Which then you're better off not using any of those classes (ie bootstrap's layout system) and make your own... for your future, you should try to understand at least on a basic level the tech you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this page to see the responsive effect!</p> 
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col-12"> 
        <h2>London</h2>
        <p>London is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
      with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <h2>Tokyo</h2>
        <p>Tokyo is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,
      and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
      <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
      it has more than 12 million inhabitants.<br></p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the third column nested inside the first one like code below

```
 <div class="col-6">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
    with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>Tokyo</h2>
      <p>Tokyo is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,
      and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because all the column in one row follows the same maximum height that one of its column has. That why London column follow the same height as the Paris column has. So when next row is started they strat below from the previous row. 
Because `.row` `.column` class does the same as CSS flexbox is done. It’s built with flexbox and is fully responsive.
read this [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: I don't think you're meant to have col's in cols. They are meant to be direct children of rows.

Comment: What is needed is 2 independent columns with many elements. There should not be any row in the display...